# I can't find open in browser option in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have WebStorm and I can't understand how exactly to open the js file in browser. I opened some help docs and it was written that I should click view and then preview in browser but I didn't see such an option.

[image]

[image]

My default browser is Firefox.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Run` option?

Comment: Related: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-browsers.html

Answer (score 1):

You can open only html (or view based files) in browsers.

[image]
You should run javascript files from your console using nodejs (if you don't wanna see UI)

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I run the javascript in the console???
I get a message that the exit code is 0 and nothing else

Comment: Go ahead and install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/about/). After that you can run js files from console, i.e. `node myscript.js`

Answer (score 0):

Choose View | Preview file in on the main menu or press Alt+F2. Then select the desired browser from the pop-up menu.

[more info](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-javascript-in-browser.html)